# refresh a <ui:define> in jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a "ui:define" in my jsf like this :

```
<ui:define name="javaScript">

<script type="text/javascript"> #{PendingTree.buildHistoryForTree} </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> #{PendingTree.buildDescriptionForTree} </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  .
  .
  .
</script>
</ui:define>
```

I want to refresh the ui:define if some event have been done;
how can I do this job ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only ajax-update JSF components.

Wrap it in a JSF component (provided that you placed this inside (bottom of) `<h:body>`).

```
<h:panelGroup id="scripts" layout="block">
    <ui:define name="scripts">
        <h:outputScript>
            #{bean.script1}
            #{bean.script2}
            .
            .
            .
        </h:outputScript>
    </ui:define>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Then you can reference it like below:

```
<f:ajax ... render=":scripts" />
```